# Launch irb while running RSpec tests for debugging purposes?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, irb

How does one launch *irb* during the runtime of my *rspec* tests?

Essentially I would like to be able to play with various things and then have my *rspec* test run on the according instance of the program. I am able to successfully do this during conventional runtime of the program, however I run into issues when I attempt to launch *irb* during runtime of an *rspec* test.

### conventional runtime

`test.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'irb'

puts 'hello world'
IRB.start
puts 'goodbye world'
```

runtime

```
$ ./test.rb 
hello world
1.9.3-p194 :001 > puts 'yo'
yo
 => nil 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > exit
goodbye world
```

### *rspec* runtime

`test_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'irb'

describe "irb" do
  it "should print 'hello world', launch irb, upon exiting irb print 'goodbye world'" do
    puts 'hello world'
    IRB.start
    puts 'goodbye world'
  end
end
```

runtime

```
$ rake spec
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/test_spec.rb
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}
hello world
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'spec_helper'
 => false
1.9.3p194 :002 > require 'irb'
 => false
1.9.3p194 :003 >
1.9.3p194 :004 >   describe "irb" do
1.9.3p194 :005 >       it "should print 'hello world', launch irb, upon exiting irb print 'goodbye world'" do
1.9.3p194 :006 >           puts 'hello world'
1.9.3p194 :007?>         IRB.start
1.9.3p194 :008?>         puts 'goodbye world'
1.9.3p194 :009?>       end
1.9.3p194 :010?>   end1.9.3p194 :010?>
 => RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2
1.9.3p194 :010 >
goodbye world
.

Finished in 0.10321 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 62613
$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [pry](http://pryrepl.org/).

Simple, fast, with syntax highlighting. After install, you just need to write:

```
binding.pry
```

in your code to stop executing and display developer debugging console

After you fall in love with pry, there is also useful gem called 'pry-nav'

Comment: @amoebe No but [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) it is far better option!  Hence I accepted this answer...

Answer (score 0):

Kicking off the debugger and then accessing IRB might work.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'ruby-debug' # Install the gem first

describe "irb" do
  it "should print 'hello world', launch irb, upon exiting irb print 'goodbye world'" do
    puts 'hello world'
    debugger
    puts 'goodbye world'
  end
end
```

Run the test, it should hit the debugger and you should see a rdb prompt. Start IRB.

```
(rdb:1) irb
1.9.3p194 :001 >
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out `binding.repl`. it can start IRB(and other ruby consoles) at runtime the same way Pry can. for example, you would say `binding.repl.irb` instead of `binding.pry` in your rspec example.

https://github.com/robgleeson/binding.repl
$ gem install binding.repl